# When I try to return the variable I am getting this error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch and return last id from SQLite but I am getting the following error.

> error: variable id might not have been initialized

Here is my method code inside databasehelper class.

```
public int getLastid() {
    int id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from sqlite_sequence where name='History'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    } else {
        id = 0;
    }
    return id; // here error comes
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last id"? Do you want the max id of the rows with `name='History'`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initiliaze your id variable, for your method :

```
int id = 0;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from sqlite_sequence where name='History'",null);
    if(cursor.getCount()==0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    }
return id;
```

Before (your code) it was not sure that you have a value in id, because your cursor can be empty and id has no value.

Comment: but I am getting 0 as id

Comment: debugged it and got id

Comment: Yes it's normal because I think you have an error in your cursor.getCount() == 0. Replace by cursor.getCount () > 0 and it's always id=0, it's a problem with your database or your query

Answer (score 1):

Set int id=0 on line no 2.
You can then skip else condition also.